# Call Django View from D3.js onclick event on Heatmap

Tags: django, d3.js, view, onclick, heatmap

Is there a way to invoke a Django view and pass it a parameter(s) from a D3.js onclick event handler associated with a heatmap? For my heatmap, I'm using the code found at the following:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_style.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: using onclick can you alert('something') in javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript code, which makes `HTTP` request when click on rectangle. Use jquery library (I am using here, in this example `$.ajax({})` is jQuery's function). You can use `Javascript's` `XMLHttpRequest` class also, to make `AJAX` call. You should just pass correct `URL` of `Django's` view. Also, use `GET` request for testing purposes to avoid `CSRF` Features of `Django`.

```
<script>

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 80, right: 25, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Read the data
        d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/heatmap_data.csv", function(data) {

          // Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'group' and 'variable'
          var myGroups = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.group;}).keys()
          var myVars = d3.map(data, function(d){return d.variable;}).keys()

          // Build X scales and axis:
          var x = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ 0, width ])
            .domain(myGroups)
            .padding(0.05);
          svg.append("g")
            .style("font-size", 15)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
            .select(".domain").remove()

          // Build Y scales and axis:
          var y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ height, 0 ])
            .domain(myVars)
            .padding(0.05);
          svg.append("g")
            .style("font-size", 15)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0))
            .select(".domain").remove()

          // Build color scale
          var myColor = d3.scaleSequential()
            .interpolator(d3.interpolateInferno)
            .domain([1,100])

          // create a tooltip
          var tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("div")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("background-color", "white")
            .style("border", "solid")
            .style("border-width", "2px")
            .style("border-radius", "5px")
            .style("padding", "5px")

          // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
          var mouseover = function(d) {
            tooltip
              .style("opacity", 1)
            d3.select(this)
              .style("stroke", "black")
              .style("opacity", 1)
          }
          var mousemove = function(d) {
            tooltip
              .html("The exact value of<br>this cell is: " + d.value)
              .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
              .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
          }
          var mouseleave = function(d) {
            tooltip
              .style("opacity", 0)
            d3.select(this)
              .style("stroke", "none")
              .style("opacity", 0.8)
          }

          // add the squares
          svg.selectAll()
            .data(data, function(d) {return d.group+':'+d.variable;})
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
              .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
              .style("fill", function(d) { return myColor(d.value)} )
              .style("stroke-width", 4)
              .style("stroke", "none")
              .style("opacity", 0.8)
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
            .on("click", function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
                console.log('clicked !!!');
                // make AJAX call now !
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '<DJANGO_VIEW_URL_HERE>',
                    data: {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'},
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('server returned status code 200');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('problem on server during processing');
                    }
                });
            })
        })

        // Add title to graph
        svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", -50)
                .attr("text-anchor", "left")
                .style("font-size", "22px")
                .text("A d3.js heatmap");

        // Add subtitle to graph
        svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", -20)
                .attr("text-anchor", "left")
                .style("font-size", "14px")
                .style("fill", "grey")
                .style("max-width", 400)
                .text("A short description of the take-away message of this chart.");
        </script>
```

Good luck.

Comment: With the same onclick event handler can I have a popup/modal/dialog opened on top of the heatmap representing another visualization for which the data will come from the <DJANGO_VIEW_URL>?